# Use AutoHotKey to remap Windows desktop commands to Numpad

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I want to remap the Windows multiple-desktop keys to the Number pad. Right now, to do it, I can press Windows+Control+Arrow key to shift between them on Windows 10, but I want to do it with the Number Pad keys because I never use them. I want to get the following combinations setup in AutoHotkey, but I don't know how to do it:

Numpad key 4 -> Win+Ctrl+Left

Numpad key 9 -> Win+Ctrl+Right

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this...

```
#Persistent
#IfWinActive

Numpad4::#^{Left}
Numpad9::#^{Right}
```

This just does a basic key reassignment.

With the script running, you can also go to the Open option via the Tray Icon and look at the Key History to see what keys are registered and/or sent (if you want to look at remapping other items.

If you need to do more than a simple key reassignment you can code it as a routine using `SendInput` and then do a `Return` at the end.

```
#Persistent
#IfWinActive

Numpad4::#^{Left}
Numpad9::
    SendInput, #^{Right}      ; does the same thing as a direct reassignment
    MsgBox, Add other code as needed for functionality or debugging
Return
```

Also, a separate but somewhat related post on Win10 virtual desktops here: [Windows virtual desktops. Cycle back to first desktop at end](https://superuser.com/questions/1176484/windows-virtual-desktops-cycle-back-to-first-desktop-at-end)